# Clean up Hard Drive and Re-install Mac

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac

I have the following MacBook

> MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013)

I want to format the hard-disk and reinstall the Mac so that I have a clean system. 
I tried to boot up with `CMD + R` and reinstall OS. Looks like it didn't wipe out the hard disk and just install the OS again.

Please let me know whats the best way forward. Read a lot of articles are they are confusing. Some say it will get into Internet recovery mode etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Boot up holding down Command R, as you did, but go to Disk Utility (under the Utilities menu) and Erase the disk before installing the OS.